# Finding classes that declare that they conform to a specific protocol using the Objective-C runtime

Tags: objective-c, runtime

I'm trying to figure out a way to "tag" classes which will be written later so I can find them at runtime, but without enforcing the usage of a specific parent classes. Currently I'm looking at perhaps applying a protocol and then finding all classes which have that protocol.

But I've not be able to figure out how.

Does anyone know if it's possible to find all classes which implement a specific protocol at runtime? or alternatively - is there a better way to "tag" classes and find them?

Comment: Aroth's answer will work, but I would suggest that you revisit your architecture and eliminate the need to do such a thing.  In general, such loosely coupled architectures will lead to very fragile code and significant maintenance/refactoring headaches in the future.   Fun, certainly, but ultimately impractical.

Comment: Normally I would, but what I'm playing with is something similar to the springframework concepts. Effectively I'm coding to operate on classes that will not exist until my framework is included in another project. What I'm attempting to do is to allow the developer to make use of what I'm doing without the requirement of extending my classes which could prove problematic if they have their own hierarchy. Thus I'm looking for ways to "tag" classes so that my framework knows to work with them.

Comment: Cool. I would suggest that you provide some abstract base classes and have the other developers inherit from that, overriding functionality as needed.   As well, having the developers effectively register their classes with your framework is also useful;  that gives them the opportunity to conditionally register some classes and not others, depending on configuration.

Comment: last night I was playing with a preprocessor define that can be put in a class and generates a new method implementation. This lets the developer use the equivalent of a Java annotation to tag a specific method. I was then able to get my software to scan the runtime and locate all the additional methods that have been added by the define and execute them to do the registration. So all the developer has to do is put in one line of code. I don't want to do an abstract base class because developers may already have one and I don't want to limit them. The only limit so far is my C knowledge. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone is interested in this old question, I eventually wrote some code the located all the bundles for the application and scanned the classes in those bundles. This was far more efficient than using code based on `objc_getClassList` because it scanned a limited number of classes as opposed to the entire runtime.

If you are interested you can find the code I was using here: https://github.com/drekka/Alchemic/blob/master/alchemic/NSBundle%2BAlchemic.m

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code that you wrote for this?

Comment: Added a link to my comment

Answer (score 28):

It doesn't look like this should be too difficult using the [Objective-C Runtime API](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html).  Specifically, it looks like you can use `objc_getClassList` and `class_conformsToProtocol` to do something like:

```
Class* classes = NULL;
int numClasses = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);
if (numClasses > 0 ) {
    classes = malloc(sizeof(Class) * numClasses);
    numClasses = objc_getClassList(classes, numClasses);
    for (int index = 0; index < numClasses; index++) {
        Class nextClass = classes[index];
        if (class_conformsToProtocol(nextClass, @protocol(MyTaggingProtocol))) {
            //found a tagged class, add it to the result-set, etc.
        }
    }
    free(classes);
}
```

Comment: I thought I might have to do that. But was hoping there was a better way because it appears that there are thousands of classes. Although I do only intend to do it once so performance is not as important. Thanks

Comment: @Derek - Yes, I'm pretty sure you have to iterate everything.  Most reflective languages do not go quite so far as to provide built-in "give me all known classes that implement X" kind of queries.  But unless you are trying to do something really elaborate it should be sufficient to perform the iteration once and cache the result.

Comment: under ARC then reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730697/using-objc-getclasslist-under-arc

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to iterate over the list of classes (objc_getClassList()) and check whether each implements the protocol in question (class_conformsToProtocol()).