# Using objc_getClassList under arc

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-runtime

Has anybody managed to use objc_getClassList under arc, short of turning arc off for the file in question?

The fundamental problem is that one of the parameters is a C array of Class pointers.

Comment: Good question. ARC seems fairly awkward in situations like this. I disabled it for the file in question, rather than spending the time to figure out how to dance around it, but like you I'd be curious to know if there's a relatively straightforward way of doing this with ARC enabled.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This code should work under ARC:

```
int numClasses;
Class *classes = NULL;

classes = NULL;
numClasses = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);
NSLog(@"Number of classes: %d", numClasses);

if (numClasses > 0 )
{
    classes = (__unsafe_unretained Class *)malloc(sizeof(Class) * numClasses);
    numClasses = objc_getClassList(classes, numClasses);
    for (int i = 0; i < numClasses; i++) {
        NSLog(@"Class name: %s", class_getName(classes[i]));
    }
    free(classes);
}
```

Comment: As a note, if you want to use one of the Class objects outside of the context where you run this code (e.g., as a return from a function that uses this), you can get an ARC memory managed Class from the __unsafe_unretained Class by doing NSClassFromString(NSStringFromClass(classes[i])). I'm not sure if there's a more efficient way to get a Class copy, but that way appears to work for me. If you just return classes[i] directly you'll end up with a dangling pointer since the object gets freed in the free(classes) call.