# How to make settings inheritance

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, settings

In my XCode project, I want some default setup settings, which basically is a set of variables like GlobalTintColor, ServerUrl and so forth. 
I then need to override some of these settings per client/target.
These settings are only for interval use, which means I'm not looking for settings bundle type solution. 
I don't want to have duplicate settings, so some sort of inheritance seems to be the right way to go.

I was thinking I'd make a parent class carrying all the default settings, and then a subclass for each client, overriding settings as needed. I just can't figure out how I'm going to load these settings. I figured only the clients that needed to override settings had a subclass. Other clients just used the default settings as defined by the parent class.

But when I'm loading the settings at application start, I then need to check if the subclass is available, and if not, I only load the super class.

But then I get the problem of what kind of class the settings are: subclass or superclass?
I've been looking into categories as well as class clustering, but haven't found a solution so far.
Seems to me this is functionality a lot of app developers need. Does any of you know of a good pattern to solve this?

To illustrate:

```
- (id) getAppConfigurationSettings {

    id settings;

    if ([AppConfigurationSettings class]) {
       settings = [AppConfigurationSettings class];
    } else {
       settings = [DefaultAppConfigurationSettings class];
    }

    return settings;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this ?

**"Parent.h"**

```
@interface Parent : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,strong)UIColor *color;
@end
```

**"Parent.m"**

```
#import "Parent.h"

@implementation Parent
-(void)setColor:(UIColor *)color{
    self.color=color;
}
@end
```

Then you create another class which will inherit `Parent` say `Child`

**Child.h**

```
#import "Parent.h"
@interface Child : Parent

@end
```

**Child.m**

```
#import "Child.h"

@implementation Child
//Override the actual color
-(void)setColor:(UIColor *)color{
    self.color=color;
}
@end
```

Then you can use it like below

```
Parent *parent=[[Parent alloc] init];
[parent setColor:[UIColor redColor]];

Child *child=[[Child alloc] init];
[Child setColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

I hope it will give you enough idea..

**Updated**

For custom initialization you can create some enum, and do your initializations accordingly like below

```
typedef enum {
    kParent     =       1,
    kChild      =       2
}kSettings;

-(void)updateColor:(kSettings)settingType{

    id classObj;

    switch (settingType) {
        case kParent:
            classObj=[[Parent alloc] init];
            break;

        case kChild:
            classObj=[[Child alloc] init];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

   [classObj setColor:[UIColor redColor]];

}
```

**Note -** The above code is not tested may not be completely correct, but can be like this.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, this part I got down. The tricky part for me is how I instantiate the right class.

Comment: For that you can have some enum defined and initialize class accordingly. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

When I hear about "base" and "override", I immediately think of a hierarchy of classes, so @iphonic answer does the job pretty well, although I would design it in a slightly different way:

"**BaseSettings**"

```
@interface BaseSettings : NSObject
... properties
@end

@implementation BaseSettings

- (instancetype) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self constantInit];
        [self dynamicInit];
    }
}

// Put here initialization that won't be overridden
// in inherited classes
- (void) constantInit {
}

// Put here initialization that will be overridden
// in inherited classes
- (void) dynamicInit {
}

@end
```

"**SettingsInheritor**"

```
@interface SettingsInheritor : BaseSettings
@end

@implementation SettingsInheritor

- (void) dynamicInit {
    // Call base method so that not overriden settings
    // are still initialized properly
    [super dynamicInit];

    // Override settings here
    ...
}
```

The `constantInit` method is for convenience only, to let you visually separate constant from overrideable settings - so you can get rid of it if you won't need or like it.

What can be improved in @iphonic's answer is how the actual settings class is instantiated, so I propose a different approach.

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1810689/148357), you can use `obj_getClassList()` to obtain the list of all registered class definitions - then you can loop through all of them, and check if its superclass is `BaseSettings` (or whatever you want to call the base settings class), using `class_getSuperClass()` or `isSubclassOfClass:`. *Note*: the latter method returns YES if subclass or identical, something to take into account when comparing.

Once you find a class inheriting from `BaseSettings`, you can break the loop and instantiate the found class (for instance using `class_createInstance()`). A (*untested*) skeleton is like this:

```
int numClasses = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);

if (numClasses > 0) {
    BOOL found = NO;
    Class settingsClass;
    Class *classes = (__unsafe_unretained Class *)malloc(sizeof(Class) * numClasses);

    for (int index = 0; index < numClasses; ++index) {
        Class curClass = classes[index];
        Class superClass = class_getSuperclass(curClass);
        const char *superClassName = class_getName(superClass);

        if (strcmp(superClassName, "BaseSettings") == 0) {
            settingsClass = curClass;
            found = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found) {
        // Create the class instance from `settingsClass`
    }

    free(classes);
}
```

Credits to [Ole Begemann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8731509/148357) for (most of) the above code