# Crash when processing __NSAtom class object

Tags: objective-c, macos, objective-c-runtime

Hi I'm using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6396390/1387438) to get list of class to automatically build some structure.

My code looks like that:

```
NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity: 32];

Class* classes = NULL;
int numClasses = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);
if (numClasses > 0 ) {
    classes = (Class*)malloc(sizeof(Class) * numClasses);
    numClasses = objc_getClassList(classes, numClasses);
    for (int index = 0; index < numClasses; index++) {
        Class nextClass = classes[index];

        if ([nextClass isSubclassOfClass: BaseCmd.class] &&
            ![BaseCmd isSubclassOfClass: nextClass]) {
            BaseCmd *cmd = [nextClass new];
            result[cmd.name] = cmd;
        }
    }
    free(classes);
}

return result;
```

So modification from answer is quite simple. It does work quite nicely until `__NSAtom` class is processed (`index = 1548` `numClasses = 7628` so it is not out of bounds problem).

When this `__NSAtom` class is reached there is a crash. Logs show:

```
*** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7fff74978938 of class '__NSAtom' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
*** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7fff74978938 of class '__NSAtom' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort
```

Crash comes from condition `isSubclassOfClass`.

Why it doesn't work? How can I fix it?

I'm using OS X Yosemite.

Comment: You should be using `objc_copyClassList`. It's significantly more efficient. (instead of acquiring a mutex twice, it only acquires once, as well as many fewer conditional branches).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+[NSObject isSubclassOfClass:]` is a class method for `NSObject` and not all classes are subclasses of `NSObject`.

It seems as if you have find private class that is not a subclass of `NSObject`, so it requires a more delicate handling for checking for inheritance. Try:

```
BOOL isSubclass(Class child, Class parent) {
    for (Class c = child; c != Nil; c = class_getSuperclass(c)) {
        if (c == parent) {
            return YES;
        }
   }
   return NO;
}
```

Comment: `NSAtom` isn't actually private (in the traditional sense)! You can create one by just casting the integer `1` to an objective-c object. It has some interesting properties: http://brian-webster.tumblr.com/post/102637339374/the-mystery-of-the-crashing-nspredicate. It's also hardcoded into the objective-c runtime and documented a little in there.